# image_proc not working as expected

Tags: ros, opencv, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to use `image_proc` to rectify my image, coming from a folder.

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>

<group ns="calibration">
    <rosparam command="load" file="/home/george/GOPRO/chessboard/calibrationdata/cal.yml"/>
    <!-- <node pkg="green_eye" name="camera_info_pub" type="camera_info_pub" output="screen" /> -->
</group>

<node pkg="green_eye" name="file_monitor" type="file_monitor" output="screen"/>
<node pkg="green_eye" name="image_processor" type="image_processor" output="screen"/>
<group ns="camera">
    <node pkg="image_proc" name="image_proc" type="image_proc" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="image_view" name="image_raw" type="image_view" output="screen">
        <remap from="image" to="image_raw" />
    </node>
    <node pkg="image_view" name="image_mono" type="image_view" output="screen">
        <remap from="image" to="image_mono" />
    </node>
    <node pkg="image_view" name="image_rect" type="image_view" output="screen">
        <remap from="image" to="image_rect" />
    </node>
    </group>
</launch>
```

The `file_monitor` node checks for new images in a folder and publishes the image path.
`image_processor` reads that path and uses `openCV` to read the image and publish it to the `/camera/image_raw` node.
It also stamps and publishes the `CameraInfo` topic in the `/camera/camera_info` path.
From there on, I expect `image_proc` to do its job, but it fails.

While the `image_raw` and `image_mono` topics are visible by the `image_view`, `image_rect` always stays grey (in fact it is never published).

I also get the following warning (not actually pasted exactly)

```
  [image_transport] Topics '/camera/image_mono' and '/camera/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
  Image messages received: 4
  CameraInfo messages received: 4
  Synchronized pairs: 0
```

`image_mono` seems to be a product of `image_proc`, but not actually a topic I publish myself, which lags `image_raw` by some 10s of ms and is displayed correctly. However, `image_raw` should be the only input of `image_proc` that I have to stamp.
Thus, I don't know why this warning should appear, or whether it affects my result.

Any ideas welcome,
Thanks in advance!

**Edit -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I managed to have the intended result with the `cv::undistort` API, but the solution is less modular and I'm not sure whether the result is as sound as the well-documented `image_proc`, so I'll leave this open.

**Edit 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Here is the code which I use to fill the `camera_info` message, having the converted `.yaml` file loaded in the parameter server:

```
pub_img_raw = it.advertise("/camera/image_raw",1);
pub_cfg = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>("/camera/camera_info",1);
    
sensor_msgs::CameraInfo cfg;
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue list;
int i;

cfg.header.frame_id = "camera";
double temp;
ros::param::get("/calibration/image_height", temp);
cfg.height = (uint)temp;
ros::param::get("/calibration/image_width", temp);
cfg.width = (uint)temp;
ros::param::get("/calibration/distortion_model", cfg.distortion_model);
ros::param::get("/calibration/distortion_coefficients/data", list);
cfg.D.clear();
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    cfg.D.push_back((double)list[i]);
}
ros::param::get("/calibration/camera_matrix/data", list);
for (i=0;i<9;i++) {
    cfg.K[i] = list[i];
}
ros::param::get("/calibration/rectification_matrix/data", list);
for (i=0;i<9;i++) {
    cfg.R[i] = list[i];
}
ros::param::get("/calibration/projection_matrix/data", list);
for (i=0;i<12;i++) {
    cfg.P[i] = list[i];
}
```

and later in the code:

```
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", image).toImageMsg();
msg->header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
msg->header.frame_id = "camera";
pub_img_raw.publish(msg);

cfg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
pub_cfg.publish(cfg);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219823/image_proc-not-working-as-expected/) by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-10-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-10-25**:
I just realized that the warning comes from `image_transport`, not `image_proc`, so one less thing to worry about. But the fact that `image_rect` is never published is still a problem.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-10-25**:
`image_transport` is used within `image_proc` so it is likely that this is indeed a thing to worry about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The warning message indicates that the Image and CameraInfo message timestamps are not synchronized. Per default, per published Image message, there should be a CameraInfo message with the exact same timestamp published. Otherwise, the default synchronization policy used by many tools with result in exactly the warning (and issues) you observe.

Note that issues with this pop up once in a while and you'll be able to find more info about time sync issues when searching this site, for instance [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/48071/image_raw-and-camera_info-not-synchronized-in-wlan/).

/edit: You call ros::Time::now twice for settings timestamps, which can lead to inconsistent stamps. Essentially the exact same issue as described [here](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy/issues/13). Not sure this will fix things, but it's a good idea to eliminate obvious potential sources of error.

Note you could also use a [CameraPublisher](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1CameraPublisher.html) for convenience.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-10-25**:
It turns out this was not the problem: /camera/camera_info is published and stamped by me. `image_proc` reads it along with `/camera/camera_raw` and produces among other things `/camera/image_mono`, but with some delay.
`image_transport` sees this and complains, but it shouldn't matter.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-10-25**:
Normally this matters as the callback of a CameraSubscriber is never called when you never have a synchronized pair.

I recommend you do not erase info from your question, as I refer to the warning message in my answer and things get very hard to understand for others.

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-10-25**:
It indeed was wrong from my part to edit the question by deleting content. I realize that now. Sorry about that. Let me re-instate the deleted content.

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-10-25**:
Thanks for taking the time to answer, Stefan. However, even though I had seen the linked thread, I can't understand how it helps.
The warning is complaining about the stamps of an `image_proc` **input** topic and an **output** topic, which seems weird to me.

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-10-25**:
To add to the conversation, I noticed that the `/rectify` [nodelet](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc#image_proc.2BAC8-diamondback.image_proc.2BAC8-rectify) of `image_proc` does use `image_mono` as input, but I sure didn't try to use it.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-10-25**:
Then everything makes perfect sense and a timestamp problem is plausible. Not sure why rectify uses image_mono per default. See updated answer.

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-10-25**:
Ugh... it was the different timestamps after all... such a silly mistake. Even for those nanoseconds `image_proc` complained.
I was used to the tf package which is not as strict with sliding frames but this time it bit me.
Thanks a bunch!